# Memory Leaks with insert(new ClassObject) in map/set

Tags: c++, dictionary, memory-leaks, set

I'm trying to insert new class objects "`Student`" in both a `map` and a `set` (each container has a different chunk of Students). To do so, I'm using `insert()` functions as demonstrated below:

```
// Map:
M.insert({ tempID, new Student(tempID, nameTemp, addressTemp, phoneTemp, numClassesTemp, gpaSumTemp) });

// Set:
S.insert(new Student(tempID, nameTemp, addressTemp, phoneTemp, numClassesTemp, gpaSumTemp));
```

My code compiles and runs fine, but memory leak checkers keep pointing to these 2 lines. Am I to use `delete`'s somewhere? Where? Or am I to include something in my Student destructor?

I took out a chunk of my code to demonstrate the problem and put it in the compilable files below. (I excluded the code for my `set`, as I believe the code for my `map` is sufficient to find the source of the memory leakage):

**Student.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    Student(unsigned long long int ID, string name, string address, string phone, int numClasses, double sum_gpa);
    ~Student();

    unsigned long long int ID;
    string name;
    string address;
    string phone;
    int numClasses;
    double gpaSum;

    string getGPA();
    string toString();
};
```

**Student.cpp:**

```
#include "Student.h"


Student::Student(unsigned long long int ID, string name, string address, string phone, int numClasses, double gpaSum)
{
    this->ID = ID;
    this->name = name;
    this->address = address;
    this->phone = phone;
    this->numClasses = numClasses;
    this->gpaSum = gpaSum;
}


Student::~Student()
{
}

string Student::getGPA(){
    string getGPA;
    stringstream ss;

    if (numClasses == 0){
        getGPA = "0.00";
    }
    else{
        ss << fixed << setprecision(2) << gpaSum / numClasses;
        ss >> getGPA;
    }

    return getGPA;
}

string Student::toString(){
    string toString;
    stringstream IDss;
    stringstream GPAss;
    string IDstr = "";
    string GPAstr = "";

    IDss << ID;
    GPAss << getGPA();
    IDss >> IDstr;
    GPAss >> GPAstr;

    toString += IDstr; toString += "\n"; toString += name; toString += "\n";
    toString += address; toString += "\n"; toString += phone; toString += "\n";
    toString += GPAstr;

    IDss.clear();
    GPAss.clear();
    return toString;
}
```

**GPA.h** (GPA.h/cpp is where the map/set-related functions are):

```
#include "Student.h"

class GPA
{

public:
    GPA();
    ~GPA();

    map<unsigned long long int, Student*> M;

    bool importStudents(string setFileName);
    void clear();
    int lineCounter(string fileName);
};
```

**GPA.cpp**

```
#include "GPA.h"

GPA::GPA()
{
}

GPA::~GPA()
{
}

bool GPA::importStudents(string mapFileName){
    fstream mapFile(mapFileName);

    /** vvv START: ERROR CHECKING vvv */
    /* Check for Invalid File(s)*/
    if (!mapFile){
        mapFile.close();
        return false;
    }
    mapFile.close();

    /* Check for Incorrect Line Count for Files */
    if (lineCounter(mapFileName) % 4 != 0){
        return false;
    }
    /** ^^^ END: ERROR CHECKING ^^^ */

    /** vvv START: IMPORT TO MAP vvv */
    mapFile.open(mapFileName);
    if (mapFile.is_open()){
        unsigned long long int tempID = 0;
        string dummySpace = "";
        string nameTemp = "EMPTY";
        string addressTemp = "EMPTY";
        string phoneTemp = "EMPTY";
        int numClassesTemp = 0;
        double gpaSumTemp = 0;
        while (mapFile >> tempID){
            getline(mapFile, dummySpace);
            getline(mapFile, nameTemp);
            getline(mapFile, addressTemp);
            getline(mapFile, phoneTemp);

            M.insert({ tempID, new Student(tempID, nameTemp, addressTemp, phoneTemp, numClassesTemp, gpaSumTemp) });
            cout << M.at(tempID)->toString() << "\n\n";
        }
    }
    /** ^^^ END: IMPORT TO MAP ^^^ */

    return true;
}

void GPA::clear(){
    for (map<unsigned long long int, Student*>::iterator it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); ++it){
        Student* m = it->second;
        delete m;
    }
        M.clear();
}

int GPA::lineCounter(string fileName) {
    std::ifstream myfile(fileName);

    // new lines will be skipped unless we stop it from happening:    
    myfile.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

    // count the newlines with an algorithm specialized for counting:
    unsigned line_count = std::count(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(myfile),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        '\n');

    return line_count;
}
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include "GPA.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    GPA myGPA;

    myGPA.importStudents("studentListMap_Small.txt");
    myGPA.importStudents("studentListMap_Large.txt");
    myGPA.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

**studentListMap_Small.txt:**

```
020961797
Joshua Cooper
0509 McCrooke Avenue, Columbus, California 52826
552-534-8671
283385788
Yazan Halawa
6707 Law Street, Madison, Alaska 01322
351-385-5237
322058308
Adam Fudge
1395 Department Street, Raleigh, Arizona 34983
287-570-5987
011812277
Paul Gibby
0940 Venice Street, Concord, Delaware 18729
779-320-4502
```

**studentListMap_Large.txt:**

```
105396824
Justin Roberts
9459 Barn Street, Bismarck, Illinois 80517
739-784-0853
760491717
Marcus Tanner
3493 Mill place, Atlanta, Virginia 96801
227-268-5713
417607834
Meza Rodolfo Amaya
8345 Dean Avenue, Albany, New Mexico 22539
596-579-2033
125363151
Paul Thornton
5944 Prague Avenue, Montpelier, Ohio 06867
181-920-3767
978344395
Brett Turley
2780 Jameson's Crossing, Frankfort, Rhode Island 55970
419-435-4046
850843037
Evan Bradham
8356 Venice Street, Raleigh, Pennsylvania 11096
573-496-1240
921190591
Sam Duzett
0767 Delaware Avenue, Jefferson City, South Dakota 48720
516-295-0387
870255828
Nathaniel Merrill
0776 P. Auerbach Avenue, Lincoln, South Carolina 59051
703-933-0882
819890357
Mark Solocinski
9900 Flower Avenue, Sacramento, Washington 09677
613-592-1728
020961797
Joshua Cooper
0509 McCrooke Avenue, Columbus, California 52826
552-534-8671
283385788
Yazan Halawa
6707 Law Street, Madison, Alaska 01322
351-385-5237
322058308
Adam Fudge
1395 Department Street, Raleigh, Arizona 34983
287-570-5987
011812277
Paul Gibby
0940 Venice Street, Concord, Delaware 18729
779-320-4502
716843573
Fridrich Perez
7656 Bay Avenue, Annapolis, Maryland 20056
469-205-9082
634930318
Michael Douglas
5575 Southern Abby Avenue, Springfield, Georgia 68675
135-483-5225
192066959
Michelle Stevens
6698 Southern Abby Avenue, Columbia, Illinois 70022
887-493-1163
741281027
Jesse Millar
7968 Museum Avenue, Des Moines, Montana 33359
084-086-9848
091487171
Sam Zamora
3657 Newhaven Avenue, Oklahoma City, Pennsylvania 32206
900-392-2156
919403007
Mark Petersen
5858 Walden Alley, Harrisburg, Louisiana 00923
802-942-4624
432610620
Chase Lundell
6721 Central cesta, Helena, Kansas 64600
300-892-2067
038218766
Ryan Bullock
7125 Eppink Square, Indianapolis, Oregon 83838
720-648-3033
207448181
Oliveros Isai Mercado
1910 King Arthur I street, Lansing, Illinois 09861
340-027-8892
578873248
Minh Do
4467 Shopping Avenue, Atlanta, Idaho 46028
489-286-6549
286617977
Anthony Constantino
2868 Highway Avenue, Harrisburg, New Mexico 62475
150-412-3674
425049135
Daniel Feller
5350 Wallstreet and, Jefferson City, Ohio 98281
422-317-1595
738936225
Scott Ryvola
7307 Flower Avenue, Pierre, Wyoming 63056
210-827-1370
383308329
David Christenson
3984 Farmer's Lane, Hartford, Florida 55765
433-499-4397
666537985
Jannae Turley
6624 Camp Street, Austin, Montana 47779
474-205-0411
356559266
Michael Kredt
1489 Francis II Street, Bismarck, Tennessee 25004
386-269-4228
535348580
Nathan Radmall
8557 Hazlett Avenue, Atlanta, Massachusetts 44369
742-936-1925
530941737
Elora Salway
8754 Queen Mary Elisabeth Alley, Springfield, Alaska 81279
215-936-2915
441365589
Cody Burt
7738 Pine Street, Carson City, Maryland 51525
407-433-7728
880738319
Mercedes Reuel
4341 Long Road Avenue, Augusta, Tennessee 93916
305-649-3653
212067186
Adam Petersen
4709 Delta Street, Raleigh, South Dakota 30268
233-788-2153
835850757
Josh Humpherys
9020 Dimitri Street, Austin, Missouri 24887
976-602-4146
318093806
Scott Saunders
3353 Jamal Hustrova Street, Santa Fe, Illinois 94000
117-310-0358
398071827
Young Tai Ahn
8528 P. Auerbach Avenue, Richmond, Indiana 38480
261-814-2605
994452189
Cherrez Andres Galan
8562 Theater Street, Boston, Ohio 54016
075-419-3779
409268016
Mat Weaver
5060 Democracy Avenue, Sacramento, South Dakota 98824
494-586-1315
725157853
Cache Staheli
7012 Industry Street, Bismarck, Mississippi 28517
453-814-0513
313757119
Christian Beesley
3126 Hendrix Avenue, Raleigh, Oklahoma 65343
173-132-3679
229435544
Dallin Cox
7264 Federation Avenue, Salem, Tennessee 37878
395-058-1800
670706814
Sam Warnick
4962 Swamp Street, Montpelier, Virginia 28540
956-752-0303
810564069
Marshall Garey
5532 Hospital Street, Harrisburg, Utah 82578
857-706-9850
139697451
Nick Wahlin
7391 Wallstreet and, Boise, Alabama 35351
629-249-0451
647744778
Nicole Viland
3063 McCrooke Avenue, Montpelier, Hawaii 48041
770-835-5060
351953580
Spencer Stock
2949 Storm Alley, Phoenix, Maryland 05300
728-001-4076
685585839
Kyle Brown
4594 Long Road Avenue, Madison, West Virginia 46981
146-275-4304
079800628
Kyle Baker
6311 Monorail Street, Charleston, Indiana 71229
762-043-7717
996857052
Jordon Ritchie
3093 New Orleans Street, Little Rock, New Hampshire 48740
457-081-6324
585472870
Jason Sevey
0405 Beatles Avenue, Charleston, Idaho 96140
829-676-5844
363108475
Sean Miller
6961 Prague Avenue, Sacramento, Louisiana 54034
008-074-9144
595315616
Raphael Pak
0703 Forest Street, Saint Paul, Washington 76921
920-396-7339
420195410
Trevor Savage
2797 Katrina Street, Little Rock, Colorado 16981
371-187-7168
451471400
Trenn Brown
3970 Adelaide Avenue, Harrisburg, Pennsylvania 99190
538-118-5794
562466352
Mackenzie Wilson
2375 Heritage Avenue, Raleigh, North Carolina 17052
489-945-0146
103805170
Samuel Lyons
6205 Mayores Road, Santa Fe, Oklahoma 44576
819-831-2871
017825823
Andrew Mello
4533 Oceana Side-Street, Juneau, New Mexico 76672
250-576-9630
902845517
Landen Barr
7033 Stone Street, Madison, South Carolina 46058
469-236-1694
819361221
Sam Farnsworth
2066 Vienna Street, Harrisburg, West Virginia 45424
412-423-4694
468756954
NATHAN Stout
0576 Maple Street, Atlanta, Mississippi 32910
555-392-3427
222487207
Justin Esplin
2874 Flower Avenue, Providence, Florida 61584
246-972-5978
996718409
Jonathan Hodnett
8498 Sylvania Avenue, Honolulu, Massachusetts 79595
183-590-7272
364801603
Garrett Porter
0732 Oceana Side-Street, Juneau, West Virginia 39951
883-447-9680
```

**memory_leak_report.txt:**

http://textuploader.com/5mejr

Comment: Why are you using `Student*`? If you change `Student*` to `Student` and `new Student` to `Student` you don't have to deal with memory leaks at all. This isn't Java. Don't write `new` everywhere.

Comment: It's an assignment, and that's how they make us structure it. Otherwise, their programs to test our code won't run. Their objective never seems to be practicality in designing these assignments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `new` needs a matching `delete`.

It looks as if `GPA` is the owner of these objects since it contains `M` and `S`, so you should delete them in `GPA`'s destructor.
You'd do that by iterating over `M` and `S` and `delete`ing every element.

Side note: you can replace

```
fstream mapFile(mapFileName);
mapFile.close();

mapFile.open(mapFileName);
```

with

```
fstream mapFile(mapFileName);
```

and

```
while (mapFile.is_open())
{
    // ...
    mapFile.close();
}
```

with

```
if (mapFile.is_open())
{
    // ...
}
```

File streams are closed when their lifetime ends, you don't need to do it manually.